# Trouble applying MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

i am having some troubles applying the MVVM pattern, for start i am following this example to learn how to apply and use the pattern...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

So my problem is establishing the "connection" between the View with the ViewModel...

In the example we have a View with a CollectionViewSource where the Source is the AllCustomers property:

```
<UserControl 
  x:Class="DemoApp.View.AllCustomersView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomerGroups" Source="{Binding Path=AllCustomers}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <ListView AlternationCount="2" DataContext="{StaticResource CustomerGroups}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="E-mail" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Email}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>            
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

who belongs to the ViewModel AllCustomersViewModel:

```
public class AllCustomersViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    (...)

    public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> AllCustomers { get; private set; }

    (...)
}
```

but he uses a ResourceDictionary where he applies a DataTemplate between the View and the ViewModel:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AllCustomersViewModel}">
    <vw:AllCustomersView />
</DataTemplate>
```

but my problem is because i am not using a ResourceDictionary, and because of that i thought that i can put the DataTemplate in the Resources of the Window where i will have my View (for me is the more logic place to put the DataTemplate)... But for some reason the Data isn't appearing in the ListView, and so i ask why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't attach the view model in the Xaml.  This hard-codes the Xaml to a specific view model.

Instead, I'd override the Application startup:

```
private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Views.MainView view = new Views.MainView();
    view.DataContext = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();
    view.Show();
}
```

See this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMQuickTutorial.aspx

This approach is also helpful if you use some sort of tool to dynamically bind your view models in the future, like MEF, Castle.Windsor or Prism.

Answer (score 1):

I never bind my view models to my view in XAML.  I prefer to have control over when that binding is set myself.  I always put a property on the View that contains the reference to the view Model.  That way I can change the view model out if needed without any unsuspecting consequences from XAML binding.  Plus doing it this way allows me to put an INotify handler on the view model so all changes are updated automatically when the view model is switched.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTemplates` without key are applied implicitly whereever data of the specified `DataType` is used as content that is to be displayed. That means that your ViewModel needs to appear somewhere, for example as the content of a `ContentControl` or an item of an `ItemsControl`.

So if you have a window you need to have an instance of the ViewModel in it:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AllCustomersViewModel}">
            <vw:AllCustomersView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Content>
        <vm:AllCustomersViewModel />
    </Window.Content>
</Window>
```

Normally you only use windows as shells though, and the content is set dynamically.

Comment: But for what i understand for now of the pattern, we use the View as Control right? So we will to instantiate the ViewModel anyway? The way i have my code he doesn't gives any error or warning, but he doesn't access the Collection to bind the data to a ListView. I have build an App very similar and the based in the example in my question but adapted to what i want...

Comment: @Miguel: You code does not show any list view, only how you created a CollectionViewSource, also whether you create a view which then creates the viewmodel or the other way around is up to you, if you create datatemplates for viewmodels that implies that you create the viewmodel first.

Comment: Yes doesn't show anywhere that i am using a ListView, but i have based my app in the MvvmDemo of the link in my question. So i am using the VM in a ListView, so i don't need to instiate it right? So what i am missing?! The only thing that i am doing different from the example of the link is that i am not using a ResourceDictionary...